# How can i setup different domains to different flow3 namespace application?

Tags: typo3-flow

I have a flow3 app that have several namespace, how can i manage to point another domain to another specific namespace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot. Not directly at least. Since the FLOW routing system is ignorant of domains, there currently is no domain-switch.

What I did, was route all requests to the main package and have a routine that runs before every request (ie. in MyAbstractController->initializeAction()).

It checks if the domain of the request is not for the main package and in that case, it would trigger an internal redirect() to the other Controller/Package.